# core difference between set and serialized in cakephp 3.0?

Tags: serialization, cakephp-3.0

```
    $player = $this->Players->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    $this->set('player', $player);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['player']);
```

if i will remove  $this->set('_serialize', ['player']) than i am not getting any difference at my view.

```
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('First Name') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->first_name) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Last Name') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->last_name) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Email') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->email) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Password') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->password) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Birthdate') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->birthdate) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Mailning Address') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->mailning_address) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('City') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->city) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('State') ?></h6>
        <p><?= h($player->state) ?></p>
        <h6 class="subheader"><?= __('Country') ?></h6>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The _serialize key is a special view variable that indicates which
>   other view variable(s) should be serialized when using a data view.
>   This lets you skip defining template files for your controller actions
>   if you don’t need to do any custom formatting before your data is
>   converted into json/xml.
>   http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key

It's a nice feature for xml and json views, but pretty much useless if you use your own view templates.